# Extending SigninManager<User> throws errors upon injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

```
public class SignInService : SignInManager<User>, ISignInService
{
    public SignInService(UserManager<User> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<User>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes, IUserConfirmation<User> userConfirmation) 
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
    {
    }
}
```

The above code throws no errors upon compilation. In fact the website has no issues until I try to activate a control upon which `SignInService` is called.

I have tried injecting each parameter individually from `SignInService` and the controller always resolves them all, however if I try to resolve `ISignInService` then it crashes.

**To rule out the obvious, I have mapped the injection in startup and tested it without extending the SignInManager.**

I've been doing a lot of research around this and I have found that the error that I am getting usually means mismatch of libraries and this is kind of where I'm a little lost how to move forward to resolve this.

I have this `signin` service in a standalone identity project and that project has the following packages:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2.0`

`Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 6.0.1`

When I look at packages there are no more updates available for me. The project is also configured for .NET 6.0 framework. `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

The more I read it sounds like there is a version that is past 2.2 but I can't find packages for it and not really sure how to resolve this error.

> MyProject.Service.SignInService..ctor(UserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory claimsFactory, IOptions optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) in SignInService.cs

> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, ref Span arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
> System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
> lambda_method27(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1<!0>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1<!0>, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions>, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1<!0>>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)'.
> at MyProject.Service.SignInService..ctor(UserManager`1 userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1 claimsFactory, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor, ILogger`1 logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method27(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Please provide exception message

Comment: What does your registration look like?

Comment: I've tried [this](https://pastebin.com/BWr7TPgu), but it works fine. Can you create a minimal reproducible example for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. So the library 2.2 is not the latest identity code as I suspected. However the nuget package does not goes past 2.2. It needs to be uninstalled and the following reference needs to be added to the project and then it works:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Lastly, the constructor now takes 7 arguments instead of 6. `IUserConfirmation<TUser>` needs to be injected as well.